# ReferenceError: filterProducts is not defined which is a Javascript Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, javascript

I want to use this Javascript Function "filterProduct".
I want to use it for kendo Dropdown as::

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("ReferenceValue") //The name of the dropdownlist is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
    .DataTextField("ValidValue") //Specifies which property of the Product to be used by the dropdownlist as a text.
    .DataValueField("ReferenceValidValueID") //Specifies which property of the Product to be used by the dropdownlist as a value.
    .BindTo(Model)
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetReferenceValidValue", "GetData").Data("filterProducts"); //Set the Action and Controller name
                })
                .ServerFiltering(true); //If true the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
            })
    .SelectedIndex(0) //Select first item.
)

<script>
    function filterProducts() {
        return {
            categories: $("#categories").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

But when I click on the Dropdown then one Exception is thrown as,

```
ReferenceError: filterProducts is not defined
```

Please help me on this that How can I use Javascript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try moving the script tag before the DropDownList declaration.